# Azure functions consumption plan queues randomly stop triggering

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

We have an app that depends heavily on function apps. There are 15 functions all in all (all of them C#). We have a timer trigger but all other 14 are queue based triggers.

Recently, all queue based triggers stop working at random. Although messages are being added to the queues none of them are being worked on. I generally have to stop and start the function app in the Azure Portal to resume. This sometimes works for weeks and other times just for a few minutes before things stop again.

Application Insights supports this as you can see from the screenshot.
[image]

The only functions to continue to execute are the timer trigger ones.

The error I get from them is:

> The listener for function '{{MyFunctionName}}' was unable to start. One or more errors occurred. Invalid storage account '{{MyStorageAccount}}'. Please make sure your credentials are correct. The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout. The client could not finish the operation within specified timeout.

This suggests maybe the storage account is offline? However I can still navigate to it using Azure Storage Explorer.

The storage account has this visual:

[image]

I don't know what "ClientOtherError" means or whether it's relevant.

Please help!

Comment: Based on the error message about the timeout, it looks like an action of some sort is causing you to loose connection to the storage account. Which shuts down your function app (for some reason).
Without a code sample it will be hard to determine. Maybe you are trying to upload/download something to your storage account?

Comment: This is pretty weird. You might try filing a bug report at [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues) with the details about your function app name, etc.

Comment: It did coincide with another function added that stores data in a Table Storage table. Sometimes this is just a couple of records in a batch and sometimes a few thousand batched. As soon as I disabled that function the issue stopped. I would be surprised if I hit some kind of limit with this though, but it appears to be the case.

Comment: Could you provide the following information so we can investigate from back end?

- Function App version (1.0 or 2.0)
- Function App name
- Function name(s) (as appropriate)
- Region

If you don't want to give your function app name, you can do so privately. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Sharing-Your-Function-App-name-privately

Comment: Thanks DixitArora - Details: ID = 68ec2b9-f9cf-4aac-88be-22e6c7ce1f67, Time: 2019-08-20T01:02:48.956, Region: Australia East

Comment: Hi Paul , will this issue occurs on Azure app service plan function with always on enabled ?

Comment: @DixitArora-MSFT the issue occured again just recently. Did you find anything at your end? It specifically occurs when I add in another function that uses table storage heavily. All queue functions stop picking up messages and all schedule triggers return the same message as above. My only option is to disable the function using table storage and then restart the app.